# How to dispose/recreate a Widget after an action

Tags: flutter

I am trying to figure out how to destroy/recreate a `Widget` based on an action (e.g: `onPressed`).

The way I thought about this, is to have my Widget rapped within an `Opacity` object, and control the state of the `Opacity` object based on user interaction somewhere in my app(i.e: hide/show the widget instead of dispose/recreate ). However, what I am asking here, how to destroy/recreating a Widget after clicking a Button?

I have created the following dummy example to show what I mean.

The red `Icon` should be disposed when I press the cloud `Icon` and recreated when I press the `RaisedButton`.

[image]

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text("Destroy/Recreate Example"),
        ),
        body: new Center(
            child: new Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Stack(fit: StackFit.passthrough,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new IconButton(icon: new Icon(
                        Icons.cloud_circle, size: 40.0, color: Colors.blue,),
                          onPressed: null /*_destroyWidget*/),
                      new Positioned(child: new DecoratedBox(
                        decoration: new BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle),
                        child: new Icon(
                          Icons.add_circle, size: 20.0, color: Colors.red,),),
                          top: 3.0,
                          left: 3.0)
                    ],
                  ),
                  new RaisedButton(onPressed: null /*_recreateWidget*/,
                    child: new Text("Recreate!"),
                  ),
                ])
        )
    );
  }
```

How to start on this idea?

**Update**

The following code achieves the same thing but by manipulating the `Opacity` of the red `Icon` (show/hide).

```
var _myOpacity = 0.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text("Destroy/Recreate Example"),
        ),
        body: new Center(
            child: new Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Stack(fit: StackFit.passthrough,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new IconButton(icon: new Icon(
                        Icons.cloud_circle, size: 40.0, color: Colors.blue,),
                          onPressed: ()=>setState((){
                        _myOpacity =0.0;
                          }) /*_destroyWidget*/),
                      new Positioned(child: new Opacity(
                        opacity: _myOpacity,
                          child:
                      new DecoratedBox(
                        decoration: new BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle),
                        child: new Icon(
                          Icons.add_circle, size: 20.0, color: Colors.red,),),),
                          top: 3.0,
                          left: 3.0)
                    ],
                  ),
                  new RaisedButton(onPressed: ()=>
                    setState((){
                    _myOpacity = 1.0;

        })
                   /*_recreateWidget*/,
                    child: new Text("Recreate!"),
                  ),
                ])
        )
    );
  }
```

Comment: What's the purpose. Why do you want to destroy and recreate? If you want the view updated, calling `setState()` should do what you want. See for example https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter/index.html#5

Comment: Out of curiosity really. But to answer your question I have thought of scenario where the user orders something in a store. Think of the cloud icon as your cart, and the recreate button as "add to cart" when pressed it adds the red icon as if "your cart has items in it". Then when you finish adding stuff, you click on the cart, an action that should remove the red icon. 

I understand how to achieve the same behavior by manipulating the state, I have added an update to the post where I show the same behavior by manipulating the `Opacity`.

Comment: If the answer below doesn't answer your question, it's probably a good idea to add a comment to the answer, so that Collin gets notified.

Comment: Sure, I am still trying to comprehend it.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You will have to wrap your red icon in a `StatefulWidget` if you want to be notified when it is initialized and disposed. A `StatelessWidget` doesn't have these callbacks.

You can replace the `StatefulWidget` with null in a `setState` and its `State` will be disposed. You can set it back to normal in a second `setState` callback, and a new `State` will be created and its `initState` will be called.

If you want to `dispose` and `initState` without going through the intermediate step of having a widget be replaced with `null`, try giving your `StatefulWidget` a new `UniqueKey` when the recreate button is pressed. This will prevent Flutter from associating the old `State` with the new `StatefulWidget`.

It seems like you're mostly doing this out of curiosity rather than a genuine use case. The shopping card example you've described probably doesn't need to use `initState` and `dispose` at all and you should just use a `StatelessWidget`.

Comment: I have update the post with some code that achieves the same behavior I am think of, but by manipulating the `opacity` property. Which means that the icon is still part of the UI, but the user just can not see it, so is this a good practice?
For your answer, I do not understand how can I set the `icon` property to null and still be able to build the UI. If you mean I need to split my class into several ones (e.g: one class for recreate and cloud, one class for the red icon). Then, how can I communicate the state between the two classes.

Comment: i.e: change the state of the red icon class, when a user action occurs on my main UI class. Am I getting your answer correctly?

Comment: Yes, you should wrap your red icon in a `StatefulWidget` if you want to be notified when it is initialized and disposed. A `StatelessWidget` doesn't have these callbacks. I updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: And you shouldn't have your parent class be notified when the `StatefulWidget` is disposed or initialized -- that breaks encapsulation of the `State` and will likely lead to bugs. This thing you're doing with `Opacity` seems really convoluted, just using `setState` to reconfigure a `StatelessWidget` is the right approach for the shopping cart example.

Comment: I am missing something, let's say I have in my main class a cart icon, and "add to cart" button, and in a separate class I have my `StatefulWidget` red icon that will appear once I press on "add to cart" in my main class, and disappear when I click on the cart icon which is also is in my main class. How to control the state of the red icon, from UI elements that does not belong to the same class. Can you please show me a working example because I am sure I am missing something?

Comment: If you want to modify the appearance of an existing `StatelessWidget`, call `setState` in some parent to trigger a rebuild, and in your `build` method ensure that your `StatelessWidget` is instantiated with the new constructor arguments you want. See https://flutter.io/tutorials/interactive/